# Properly extending AppWidgetProvider and IntentService in a Free / Pro combo

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have a code base that has a working widget. The basic structure of this is

```
MyAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
MyWidgetService extends IntentService
```

`MyWidgetService` updates `MyAppWidget` and all was well until I decided to turn my app into a library to create a "free / pro" combo from the same code base. Now I have something like this

```
com.example.myapp.free.MyAppWidget extends com.example.myapp.library.MyAppWidget
com.example.myapp.pro.MyAppWidget extends com.example.myapp.library.MyAppWidget
com.example.myapp.library.MyAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
com.example.myapp.library.MyWidgetService extends IntentService
```

`MyWidgetService` runs a *MyAppWidget.update()* method in order to update the display.

In this case, the widgets have minor tweaks to adjust for the version of the app and everything displays fine, but `MyWidgetService` doesn't update the widgets.

I've verified that `MyWidgetService` actually runs as scheduled but it doesn't know what update method to call. As it stands `MyWidgetService` will call *com.example.myapp.library.MyAppWidget.update()* instead of the pro or free versions.

I was able to pass down a flag and tell it which widget class it is, but that means my parent class (library `MyWidgetService`) needs to know details about the pro / free classes to update. This breaks the proper object orientated model.

My question is, what is the proper way to communicate which widget class should be updated?

Since this is a difficult thing to explain, below are some skeleton details of my classes in case it helps explain things.

Any help is appreciated.

**Library MyWidgetService**

```
public class MyWidgetService extends IntentService {

    public MyWidgetService() {
        super(MyWidgetService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // this calls the update method of the widget
        // but it doesn't know which object to call
        MyAppWidget.update();
        scheduleNextUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);       
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void scheduleNextUpdate() {         
        // schedule next time for the service to work
    }   
}
```

**Library MyAppWidget**

```
public class MyAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public static void update() {
        // update widget display
    }
}
```

**Free MyAppWidget that extends Library MyAppWidget**

```
public class MyAppWidget extends com.example.myapp.library.MyAppWidget {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        // setup free widget
        // what can I do here to pass down to the service
        // to make sure it updates this widget class
    }
}
```

**Free app manifest**

```
<!-- use the extended widget from com.example.myapp.free -->
<receiver
    android:name=".MyWidgetApp"
    android:label="@string/clock_widget_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/clock_widget" />
</receiver>
<!-- use the service from the library project -->
<service android:name="com.example.myapp.library.MyWidgetService" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was able to pass down a flag and tell it which widget class it is, but that means my parent class (library MyWidgetService) needs to know details about the pro / free classes to update. This breaks the proper object orientated model.

Instead of passing the flag, pass the fully-qualified class name, and use reflection to access it.

Or, make `update()` be an instance method, triggered by a custom broadcast action and dispatch logic in `onReceive()`. Then have the service send a matching broadcast.

Comment: I like the broadcast idea. So I'm clear on what you mean with it (lots of Java jargon in there), I should send a boadcast message from the `IntentService` which triggers a `BroadcastReceiver` and from the receiver, the widget display is updated?

Comment: @Kirk: Your `AppWidgetProvider` *is* a `BroadcastReceiver`. I am saying that you can send a broadcast from your `IntentService` to your `AppWidgetProvider`.

Comment: Ahh, genius! So much cleaner that way. Thank you.